# Migrating blobs from Classic subscription to v6 subscription

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I wantd to know whether there is a way to migrate the storage blobs from Classic subscription to V6 subscription on Azure as we can do for the VMs.

Thank you.

Comment: What is a V6 subscription?

Comment: I've never heard of "V6" subscription. Where did you see this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to move classic azure storage to a new subscription as an ARM resource? At currently, Azure storage services is supported to move to a new resources or a new subscription. We could find this information at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#services-that-enable-move). In that article, we could find that there will be some limitations for moving classic deployment to a new subscription. Here is a snippet of that article:

- All classic resources in the subscription must be moved in the same
  operation.
- The target subscription must not contain any other classic
  resources.
- The move can only be requested through a separate REST API for
  classic moves. The standard Resource Manager move commands do not work when moving classic resources to a new subscription.

It also provide detailed steps about how to move Classic Compute to a new subscription. If you want to move classic storage. Please try to use "ClassicStorage" instead of "ClassicCompute"
We could find the provider in [Azure resource portal](https://resources.azure.com/). for example. I want to move "jaml" to a new subscription. I search "jaml" in Azure resource portal. then I will find below information:

[image]